# How do i get all twig templates to inherit from master?

Tags: php, twig

NB: i´m using Twig in a non-Symfony context.

I want to register a master layout that all templates should inherit, so that i don´t have to forget to preface them with:

`{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}`

I know i have seen this somewhere, and Symfony makes use of it.

Comment: does not your code work? it is valid

Comment: Yes, but i want all templates to extend 'layout.html.twig' without adding it in each template file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible!

After some experimenting i came up with this solution:

```
{# index.html.twig #}   
{% block title %}Hello world{% endblock%}
```

Wrap global layout in a block:

```
{# layout.html.twig #}
{% block layout %}
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>{% block title %}{% endblock%}</title>
        </head>
    <html>
{% endblock %}
```

Pass child template to twig:

```
// index.php
...
$twig->display(array('template'=>'index.html.twig'));
...
```

Inject child template via a proxy template:

```
{# proxy.twig #}
{% extends 'layout.html.twig' %}
{% block layout %}
    {# Get extended block #}
    {{ parent() }}
    {# inject template into master layout #}
    {% include template %}
{% endblock %}
```